# De-quantising audio with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, signal-processing, libavcodec

I am using FFmpeg library to decode and (potentially) modify some audio.

I managed to use the following functions to iterate through all frames of the audio file:

```
avformat_open_input // Obtains formatContext
avformat_find_stream_info
av_find_best_stream // The argument AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO is fed in to find the audio stream
avcodec_open2 // Obtains codecContext
av_init_packet

// The following is used to loop through the frames
av_read_frame
avcodec_decode_audio4
```

In the end, I have these three values available on each iteration

```
int dataSize; // return value of avcodec_decode_audio4
AVFrame* frame;
AVCodecContext* codecContext; // Codec context of the best stream
```

I supposed that a loop like this can be used to iterate over all samples:

```
for (int i = 0; i < frame->nb_samples; ++i)
{
    // Bytes/Sample is known to be 4
    // Extracts audio from Channel 1. There are in total 2 channels.
    int* sample = (int*)frame->data[0] + dataSize * i;
    // Now *sample is accessible
}
```

However, when I plotted the data using `gnuplot`, I did not get a waveform as expected, and some of the values reached the the limit of 32 bits integers: (The audio stream is not silent in the first few seconds) [image: Plot]

I suppose that some form of quantisation is going on to prevent the data from being interpreted mathematically. What should I do to de-quantise this?

Comment: At a typical sample rate of 44.1kHz, 18,000 samples is around 4.3 seconds, so of course you're not seeing a typical waveform. Try zooming in and see if it looks unlike what you'd expect.

Comment: @Linuxios I zoomed in to about `100ms` ( 4410 samples) and the graph does show some periodicity, but the magnitude does not reflect the audio's volume as it frequently reaches +/- 2147483647

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Something can cover the full range of 24-bit audio and still be played back quietly. If you open the original file in something like Audacity, what do you see if you look at the same part of the waveform?

Comment: @Linuxios The first `80ms` is silent, and there is a little bit of fluctuation on the `[80,100]ms` range.

Comment: OK. That is weird :). Never mind me...

Comment: What format is your original audio file?  If it's PCM or WAV and you specify the endianness wrong when you open it I'd expect the decoding to succeed without errors but the output samples will be garbled similar to yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < frame->nb_samples; ++i)
> {
>     // Bytes/Sample is known to be 4
>     // Extracts audio from Channel 1. There are in total 2 channels.
>     int* sample = (int*)frame->data[0] + dataSize * i;
>     // Now *sample is accessible
> }
> ```

Well... No. So, first of all, we'll need to know the data type. Check `frame->format`. It's an [enum AVSampleFormat](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__sampfmts.html#gaf9a51ca15301871723577c730b5865c5), most likely flt, fltp, s16 or s16p.

So, how do you interpret `frame->data[]` given the format? Well, first, is it planar or not? If it's planar, it means each channel is in frame->data[n], where n is the channel number. `frame->channels` is the number of channels. If it's not planar, it means all data is interleaved (per sample) in `frame->data[0]`.

Second, what is the storage type? If it's s16/s16p, it's `int16_t *`. If it's flt/fltp, it's `float *`. So the correct interpretation for fltp would be:

```
for (int c = 0; c < frame->channels; c++) {
    float *samples = frame->data[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < frame->nb_samples; i++) {
        float sample = samples[i];
        // now this sample is accessible, it's in the range [-1.0, 1.0]
    }
}
```

Whereas for s16, it would be:

```
int16_t *samples = frame->data[0];
for (int c = 0; c < frame->channels; c++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < frame->nb_samples; i++) {
        int sample = samples[i * frame->channels + c];
        // now this sample is accessible, it's in the range [-32768,32767]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the amplitude corresponding to the edge values? (`+/-1.0` for floating point, and `-32768,32767` for integer)

Comment: The edge values are scale of the signal, and the amplitude (relative to scale) of the signal is the loudness (volume) of the audio signal.

Comment: Is it normal to encounter NaN and out of bound values while reading FLTP?

Comment: NaN: no, shouldn't happen. OOB: yes, that can happen.